# Webcam isn't working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, skype, webcam, camera

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 x64(Lenovo G510, intel i5) but cheese is not working, nor skype.

The first thing I did was

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

I then tried to install cheese `sudo apt-get install cheese` but I think it was already there as this was the output.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cheese is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 322 not upgraded.


eric@eric:~$ sudo lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`eric@eric:~$ sudo modprobe uvcvideo`   gives nothing ~ no output

same for `sudo rmmod uvcvideo`

```
eric@eric:~$ dmesg | grep uvcvideo
[91469.832413] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[91839.384427] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
[92126.932716] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[92166.125643] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
```

And I get this when I run cheese:

```
eric@eric:~$ cheese 
** Message: cheese-application.vala:291: Error during camera setup: No device found


(cheese:31540): cheese-CRITICAL **: cheese_camera_device_get_device_node: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:31540): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:31540): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:31540): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:31540): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

** (cheese:31540): CRITICAL **: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed
```

## EDIT:

```
eric@eric:~$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/14p, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rts5139, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
```

Comment: Could you [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/505063/edit) in the output of `lsusb -t`?

Comment: @Wilf : edited! Please look at the edited question

Comment: @user3810188 show us $ls /dev/vid*

Comment: Is your user part of the video group? Try `useradd -G video username` and check again if it works...

Comment: Try out of a Live-System and check your cam if it work reply result?

Comment: Sounds silly but do a system upgrade `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should install UVC driver. You can get information on troubleshoot webcam issues from this link.[Click here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam)

Comment: I installed guvcview as you can read in the bounty comment at the end of the question. This indeed solved my webcam issue for 13.10 but does not do the trick for 14.04

Comment: Which version have you installed??                                     You can check out this [link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-guvcview-1-7-3-ubuntu1404/) See if it solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue ... closely look at your keyboard to see if you have a multifunction key with a webcam icon ... for my keyboard the F6 key multi function icon looks like a webcam ... so I hold down the Fn key (often its purple) and F6 key to toggle on/off ability to use the webcam

ubuntu 14.04 and above comes by default with necessary drivers